# Basically, need to decode/list data from an array of collections

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method in a controller as follows-

```
public function referrals()
{
    $referrals = Users::all()->where('referrer', Auth::user()->mobileNumber);

    foreach($referrals as $referral) {
        $children[] = Users::all()->where('referrer', $referral->mobileNumber);
    }

    return view('referrals', compact('referrals','children'));
}
```

And I am displaying the resulting data in a view as follows:

```
@foreach($referrals as $referral)
    @if($referral->firstName !=="")

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h3>
                {{ $referral->firstName.' '.$referral->lastName.' ('.$referral->mobileNumber.')' }}
                @else
                    Empty
            </h3>
            @endif

            @foreach($children as $child)
                <h5>
                    {{ $child->firstName.' '.$child->lastName.' ('.$child->mobileNumber.')' }}
                </h5>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

The referrals part is displayed properly, but the children part is not being displayed. Before using `$children[]`, I used `children` and I was able to display data but the result set of the last iteration overwrote the whole result set.

Output of `dd()` -

[image: Had to upload the image, as SO wasn't allowing to post dd() data.]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have any association of between a $referral and it's $children.

You might want to do it like this:

```
public function referrals()
{
    $referrals = Users::all()->where('referrer', Auth::user()->mobileNumber);

    foreach($referrals as &$referral) {
        $referral->children = Users::all()->where('referrer', $referral->mobileNumber);
    }

    return view('referrals', compact('referrals'));
}
```

And then in your view iterate like:

```
@foreach($referrals as $referral)    
        <div class="col-md-3">
        @if($referral->firstName !=="")
            <h3>
                {{ $referral->firstName.' '.$referral->lastName.' ('.$referral->mobileNumber.')' }}
                @else
                    Empty
            </h3>
        @endif

            @foreach($referral->children as $child)
                <h5>
                    {{ $child->firstName.' '.$child->lastName.' ('.$child->mobileNumber.')' }}
                </h5>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
```